# Getting exception on SQLite create Table

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have getting exception when hitting line:  database.CreateTableAsync().Wait();

Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.

Comment: You must show the exception trace to us.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Parmendrakumar/514fe70c1a5f6763962766745d045249

Comment: My OnAppearing code:
  var query = App.Database.GetItemsAsync().Result;

                foreach (TodoItem var1 in query)
                {
                    TextContainer.Add(new MessageText { Text = var1.Text, Status = var1.Status, DateSent = var1.DateSent });

                }

Comment: Remove`.Wait();` when creating table and instead use await to see if it works.

Comment: After removing wait I am getting exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'SQLite.SQLiteConnection' threw an exception.

Comment: Hmm, I think maybe there's an issue in your table class model. Are you sure all fields are valid SQLite data types?.

Comment: On your note `SQLite.SQLiteConnection` is throwing an exception, but in your question you have mentioned `CreateTableAsync()`. Are you trying to use async methods on a synchronous connection? You should be using `SQLiteAsyncConnection` in order to call that method

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have resolved its issue with SQLiteAsyncConnection